# Regex - capture all repeated iteration

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I have a variable like this

```
var = "!123abcabc123!"
```

i'm trying to capture all the '123' and 'abc' in this var.

this regex `(abc|123)` retrieve what i want but...

My question is: when i try this regex `!(abc|123)*!` it retrieve only the last iteration. what will i do to get this output

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-4]   `123`
MATCH 2
1.  [4-7]   `abc`
MATCH 3
1.  [7-10]  `abc`
MATCH 4
1.  [10-13] `123`
```

https://regex101.com/r/mD4vM8/3

Thank you!!

Comment: It depends on the language you are using. If it is .NET, all the captured texts are in `Captures` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your language supports `\G` then you may free to use this.

```
(?:!|\G(?!^))\K(abc|123)(?=(?:abc|123)*!)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD4vM8/6)

Comment: Can you please explain what this regex do.

Comment: You may see  the explanation at the right side in the link I attached.. Soorry, I have some work..