# Find all matches between delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find all single letters between `!` and `!`.

For example, the string `!abc!` should return three matches: `a`, `b`, `c`.

I tried the regex `!([a-z])+!`, but it returns just one match: `c`. `!(([a-z])+)!` also doesn't help.

```
import re

s = '!abc!'
print(re.findall(r'!([a-z])+!', s))
```

UPD: Needless to say, it should also work with the strings like `!abcdef!`. The number of characters between the delimiters is not fixed.

Comment: If the input is `"!abc!def!ghi!jkl!"`, what should the output be?

Comment: Your parenthesis are in the wrong spot, `re.findall(r'!([a-z]+)!', s)`. Though this solution will still not work for cases such as @Kevin 's.

Comment: @Kevin `"!abc!def!ghi!jkl!"` is an invalid string, so it shouldn't match. Only `[a-z]` allowed between the delimiters.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse That returns 1 match with `['abc']`

Comment: A string is iterable. Just turn it to a list.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse so no way to do it within a single regex?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov They are two somewhat different operations, and I don't see a way of doing this just with a single regex.

Comment: When you say that `"!abc!def!ghi!jkl!"` is an invalid string, do you mean that you don't care what the result is, because that kind of string will never be input? Or do you mean that the result _must_ be None, in order to distinguish it from valid strings?

Comment: @Kevin I meant I don't care, because such string will never appear.

Comment: Found a solution finally! Please check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55691701/4732334

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Not sure why this was upvoted, but wanted to give you these. `>>> string = '''!abc!def!ghi!jkl!mno!'''` .... **1.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([\S]+?)(?:!)*', string)`,, **2.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([\S])(?:!)*', string)`,, **3.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([a-z])(?:!)*', string)`,, etc. ..... `#OUTPUT  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']`

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov Or are you saying it will appear within larger text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm answering my own question. Found a solution, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992934/4732334).

First off, an alternative `regex` module is needed, because the regex below uses the `\G` anchor.

Here is the regex:

`(?:!|\G(?!^))\K([a-z])(?=(?:[a-z])*!)`

Works like a charm.

```
import regex

s = '!abcdef!'
print(regex.findall(r'(?:!|\G(?!^))\K([a-z])(?=(?:[a-z])*!)', s))
```

Prints `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`.

Comment: Why would this need to be THAT complicated? Why not just use `>>> string = '''!abc!def!ghi!jkl!mno!'''` .... **1.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([\S]+?)(?:!)*', string)`,, **2.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([\S])(?:!)*', string)`,, **3.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([a-z])(?:!)*', string)`,, etc.

Comment: Or are you saying it will appear within larger text?

Comment: @FailSafe YES, it is THE best solution! Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: Honestly, it is only the best for that specific string. If you had `>>> string = '!abc!def!ghi! blah blah blah !ghi!jkl!mno!'` or even `>>> string = 'abcdefghij'` it would not be the best and would still match. I'll look into an easier solution later today.

Answer (score 1):

You should place the capture group around `([a-z]+)`, including the entire repeated term.  Then, you may use `list()` to convert the match into a list of individual letters.

```
s = '!abc!'
result = re.findall(r'!([a-z]+)!', s)
print list(result[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, it's certainly an option. But is there really no way to do it within a single regex?

Comment: The thing is, you really need two regex patterns here, one to isolate the text in between the bangs `!`, and then another to split (or in this case, just use `list()`).

Comment: `regex` is designed to find a string not to convert that string to chars.  Is there a reason you need it as a list of `chars`

Comment: It just looks a bit illogical that for a string `abc` it's easy to get each character using a regex `([a-z])`. But for a string `!abc!` it becomes impossible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `>>> string = '''!abc!def!ghi!jkl!mno!'''` .... **1.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([\S]+?)(?:!)*', string)`,, **2.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([\S])(?:!)*', string)`,, **3.** `>>> re.findall('(?:!)*([a-z])(?:!)*', string)`,, etc. .....  `#OUTPUT  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And group matches `re.findall('(?:!)*([a-z]+)(?:!)*', string)` .... `#OUTPUT ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']`

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=!.*)\w(?=.*!)` Should return the result you want, each character individually

Comment: But what would happen with an input like `!abc!blah` ?

Comment: I'm getting an error: `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Answer (score -1):

I look into your problem, please follow the following logic inside your expression

```
s = '!abc!'
print(re.findall(r'!([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])!',s))
```

each character is divided into groups to get them individually in an array.

Comment: It should work with the strings like `!abcdef!`, the number of characters between the delimiters is not fixed.